# Why is my unpacked chrome extension changing the dimensions of websites (ie. Github, Linkedin, etc.)

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on developing a chrome web extension. I have had no issues so far as I was using inline styles with HTML. Once I decided to create a css file to hold my extensions styles and loaded the unpacked file into Chrome whenever I visted websites like linkedin or Github they would be squished to the left side of the screen. I will provide screenshots below. Any advice on how to fix this issue would be awesome!

[GitHub before extension is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfA9o.jpg)

[GitHub after extension is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbLtL.png)

Currently my styles provide specific dimensions for the entire extension using the body tag, I am wondering if GitHub is some how being affected by these dimensions.

I reverted back to using inline styles and the issue appears to have gone away. This seems to be solely a seperate css file issue with loading the unpacked chrome extension.

Comment: You probably specified the style in content_scripts `css` key, which applies it to all matching sites. Note that `content_scripts` is for js/css that is applied to sites, not to your extension, so you should remove this key if that wasn't your intention.